# How to get plain text files in Doxygen documentation?

Tags: text, text-files, doxygen, doxywizard

I cannot include any text file in my Doxygen documentation. The only exception is a `README.md` file that I set as the main page.

In particular, I would like to see the `Changelog.txt` file in the documentation. I tried to add it explicitly in the `INPUT` field and in the `FILE_PATTERNS` field, without success. In the generated HTML documentation, I cannot find anything neither in the file list nor making a search.

The only trace is in Doxygen's log file:

```
Preprocessing C:/Source/Changelog.txt...
Parsing file C:/Source/Changelog.txt...
...
Parsing code for file Changelog.txt...
```

---

If I change the extension of the file from `txt` to `md`, the file is added to the documentation.

Comment: Do you have `doxygen` header at the top of your `Changelog.txt`? There is no `Generating docs for ...` in your output.

Comment: No, it is a plain text file.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want is possible in `doxygen` then.

Comment: which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: 1.8.13, the latest one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `EXTENSION_MAPPING=txt=md` otherwise the `.txt` file is handled as a `C / C++` source file and it is missing comment signs, resulting in no output.

From the documentation:

> EXTENSION_MAPPING Doxygen selects the parser to use depending on the
>   extension of the files it parses. With this tag you can assign which
>   parser to use for a given extension. Doxygen has a built-in mapping,
>   but you can override or extend it using this tag. The format is
>   ext=language, where ext is a file extension, and language is one of
>   the parsers supported by doxygen: IDL, Java, Javascript, C#, C, C++,
>   D, PHP, Objective-C, Python, Fortran (fixed format Fortran:
>   FortranFixed, free formatted Fortran: FortranFree, unknown formatted
>   Fortran: Fortran. In the later case the parser tries to guess whether
>   the code is fixed or free formatted code, this is the default for
>   Fortran type files), VHDL. For instance to make doxygen treat .inc
>   files as Fortran files (default is PHP), and .f files as C (default is
>   Fortran), use: inc=Fortran f=C. Note: For files without extension you
>   can use no_extension as a placeholder. Note that for custom extensions
>   you also need to set FILE_PATTERNS otherwise the files are not read by
>   doxygen.

Comment: Do you mean: "You need `EXTENSION_MAPPING=txt` otherwise..."?

Comment: Sorry wrong syntax (and a bad word, thanks for correcting), I'll correct the answer

Comment: Is it `EXTENSION_MAPPING=txt=md` or  `EXTENSION_MAPPING=txt,md` ?

Comment: OK, so does the `EXTENSION_MAPPING=txt=md` syntax mean "process txt files with Markdown parser"?

Comment: Yes with the doxygen Markdown parser.